# Import-Module succeeds, but runs old version

Tags: powershell

Good morning,

I have the following PowerShell code:

```
function Get-Phone {
    param(
        [string] $name
    )

    Write-Output "here"
    (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$name'" -properties IPPhone | Select-Object ipphone).ipphone

}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-Phone
```

I have it in the correct directory `%userprofile%\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Get-Phone\Get-Phone.psm1`

I added the `Write-Output` to make sure this new version was getting run. It was. I changed a small piece, then changed "here" to "heeeere" to make sure the new version was being run. I ran `Import-Module Get-Phone` successfully, however the new version of the module is not being run and it still writes "Here" instead of "heeere". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `-Force`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This did not work

Comment: @ryanbroman `Remove-Module Get-Phone; Import-Module ...`